# Data aggregation with facebook prophet

Tags: time-series, python, prophet

I'm using facebook's prophet library for forecast, the library seems to work very well but I'm not finding in the documentation how to handle multiple values for the same period, E.G:

I'm working with a daily frequency and in some cases, for the same day I have several values in the input:

```
{'ds': {'0': '2019-07-08T00:00:00Z',
  '1': '2019-07-10T00:00:00Z',
  '10': '2019-07-17T00:00:00Z',
  '100': '2019-10-14T00:00:00Z',
  '101': '2019-10-15T00:00:00Z'},
 'value': {'0': -546.4286315139158,
  '1': -1346.4796483895964,
  '10': -1205.169348580975,
  '100': -1071.2556594090804,
  '101': -1542.022819394989}}
```

Easier to read in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem to have several observations on the same day. The prophet library allows it.

The reason why it is not a problem is because prophet is a regression method and it is no problem to give two observations with the same covariate to a regression method.

(The prophet paper: https://doi.org/10.7287/peerj.preprints.3190v2)

Comment: which is why it assumes a single time trend without any breakpoints (i.e. changes in trend ) AND additionally totally ignores the presence of possible multiple step/level shifts which can lead to mis-classification . Note fitting powers of time  (Time squared , Time cubed , et al) does not speak to time trend point changes but rather obfuscates.